# Why can't I HtmlDecode in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

Here is the scenario. I want to use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for a rich text field on a form, but for whatever reason I cannot get the contents from the textarea to the server and back to the page without encoding problems. Here is the little sample program I wrote up to try and figure out what is going on. First, my view model:

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
namespace CkEditorTest.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Html)]
        [Display(Name = "Note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now my controller:

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CkEditorTest.Models;

namespace CkEditorTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new HomeViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, my view:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model CkEditorTest.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CKEditor Test";
}
@section head
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Note").ckeditor();
        });
    </script>
}

<h2>CKEditor Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)<br /><br />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note)<br />
    <input type="submit" />
}

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Note))
{
<div id="noteText">@Model.Note</div>
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot display the **Model.Note** property as html on my view. By the time it reaches the view it is HTML encoded (i.e. <p> etc...). Here is what the form looks like pre-post:

[pre-post http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/pre-post.png](http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/pre-post.png)

And here is what the result is in the div below the "Submit" button:

[post result http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/posted.png](http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/posted.png)

I've set a breakpoint within Visual Studio and it shows as bare angle brackets (no encoding on HTML elements, just characters).

[breakpoint results http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/dataInsideTheActionMethod.png](http://www.matthewkimber.com/images/so/dataInsideTheActionMethod.png)

This, of course, is the stripped down test. I've tried encoding it, decoding it both in the view and in the controller to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default everything is encoded when you use razor. I think you're looking for the [Raw method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

It would also be a good idea to check the response using Fiddler or Firebug.

Comment: Also see http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx

Comment: Good one. Bad name on the method tho, har to find. You don't think to look for "raw"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Note)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use HtmlString("")